All of a sudden, I'm being barred from using fontawesome by a CORS policy
I have an account with fontawesome, and prior to today, this include code in my header always worked:
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/MYSPECIALCODE.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Now, even when I test it on localhost, I get this error message:
localhost/:1 Access to script at 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/MYSPECIALCODE.js' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

(MYSPECIALCODE means the code that fontawesome gives me to include in a link.)
What's going on? My project goes live tomorrow.

The Font Awesome Kit service is down. We have the same issue right now. So does BenchApp.
https://status.fortawesome.com/

I wonder if this is related to the Funds drive they are doing right now that just wrapped up?  Perhaps they are patching the services.  Hopefully some you the devs planned ahead and put a local copy on your servers to point to in times like this.  Granted its for Webawesome, but perchance there is some correlation?
